# How to replace characters before a number in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table **Port** with data like the following:

```
Name
-------
ADSL 1
ADSL 2
Ethernet 1
Ethernet 2
```

and I want to transform the data to:

```
Name
-------
Port 1
Port 2
Port 1
Port 2
```

How can I do a

```
update Port set name =  somereplacmentlogic(name)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your RDBMS

Comment: @StephLocke alig's REPLACE answer was an approach i began with, just wasn't all encompasing, but will work for my needs, was really looking for a more ubiquitous approach.

Comment: So, what dbms are using? Oracle? Mysql? Sql-Server?

Comment: Depending on RDBMS you can use regex to replace all alphabetical characters with a 'Port' which would enable a one-step solution - but it depends on support for regex by the database engine.  Alternatively, you can always replace all bar the last character (using the correct variants of len, left, right etc) but again syntax tends to be RDBMS specifc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure, what DBMS you are using, but if it supports regular expressions, you can do something like:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Name, SUBSTR(Name, 1, REGEXP_INSTR( Name, '[0-9]', 1)-1), 'Port ')
 FROM PORT
```

REGEXP_INSTR( Name, '[0-9]', 1) will locate the place, where the first numeric character appears.

SUBSTR(Name, 1, REGEXP_INSTR( Name, '[0-9]', 1)-1) will return the substring from the beginning of your column value till the numeric value. And replace will replace that returned value inside the string.

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE Port SET Name = REPLACE(Name, 'ADSL', 'Port');`

`UPDATE Port SET Name = REPLACE(Name, 'Ethernet', 'Port');`